# How to connect Jira Cloud data to a web-app

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have a node.js web-app added to jira as user-installed app.

My app has some simple data:

```
{name: process_1},
{name: process_2},
{name: process_3}
```

What I need to do is:

1. Add a custom field named `"tl_process"` to the New Issue jira form
2. Have `tl_process` field list all the data from my app, eg: `"process_1", "process_2", "process_3"` as selectable values

   2.1 Important note: these values should be supplied to jira by my webapp
3. When a user creates new jira issue with `tl_process` value `process_2` for example - my webapp should receive a notification about it. Then I will set my data to:

   {name: process_1, active: true}

What would be the best course of action to follow here?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Add a custom field named "tl_process" to the New Issue jira form

If you want the field to be seen in the issue view, you might want to consider using the [Issue Field](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/modules/issue-field/) module. If you really want a custom field, check the REST API [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/?utm_source=%2Fcloud%2Fjira%2Fplatform%2Frest%2F&utm_medium=302#api-api-3-field-post).

> 2. Have tl_process field list all the data from my app, eg: "process_1", "process_2", "process_3" as selectable values

If you go the Issue Field route, you can also add values by using [Create issue field option](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/?utm_source=%2Fcloud%2Fjira%2Fplatform%2Frest%2F&utm_medium=302#api-api-3-field-fieldKey-option-post) REST API.

> When a user creates new jira issue with tl_process value process_2 for example - my webapp should receive a notification about it. Then I will set my data to:

For this, you need to create an endpoint on your app and trigger a [webhook](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/webhooks/) to call your app.

Comment: For issue field module, you can use the template property, or your app can call the Create issue field option REST API